# show a process's detail by id on linux

Tags: linux, process, pid

on linux can I show a process's detail including what command/script started it, etc?
top is show all processes and I wish to get more information on a process using its id

Answer (score 12):

```sh
ps -p <pid> -lF
```

...will give you information about the process like which command started it, time it was started, its state, parent pid, size etc.

If you can tell in more detail as what all information you want to know about process from pid, then we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

You can find lots of information in /proc/{PID} directories.

Comment: how is that useful for op? - please provide additional information to describe how to navigate that folder and how to interpret different files.